# スクロールバー表示の仕方について

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui, html5, scrollview

OnsenUIとjQueryでハイブリッドアプリを作っておりますが、
検索リストのような画面でスクロールバーを表示したいのですが仕方が解りません。

ページの基本構造は以下の通りです。

```
<ons-navigator var="onsnav_search">
<ons-page ng-controller="ctrl_search.html">
<ons-toolbar style="height: 110px;" fixed-style></ons-toolbar>

<div id="id-main">
<ul class="cs-ulh" id="ul-search">
<li></li><li></li>....<li></li>
</ul>
</div>

</ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

OnsenUI側なのかjQuery側の問題なのかも不透明な状況ですが、
少なくともスクロールバーを明示的に無効にするような記述はありません。

ons-pageの中身はスクロール無効になるのかと疑って試してみましたが、
どうやらそうではないようです。そもそもスライディングメニューを実装
するためにはons-pageは必須と理解しております。
根本的な問題のような気もしているのですがアドバイス頂けますと大変幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

iScroll5を使ってみてはどうでしょうか。

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5

```
_iscroll = new IScroll(_$obj.get(0),
{
    scrollbars:     true,
    fadeScrollbars: true
});
```

ただ、OnsenUIはiScroll4を内包してたと思うので併用は無理、または思うように動作しないかもしれません。私はOnsenUI使っていないのでこれで対応しています。